# OAuthException handling with IOS facebook library

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the following response from facebook when using the ios fb library.

```
{"error":{"message":"Error validating access token: The session was invalidated explicitly using an API call.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"error_subcode":466}}
```

I am using the below code to make this request:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xxxxxx" andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    NSLog(@"FB: taking saved token");
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
} else {
    NSLog(@"FB: session already valid");
}

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

And below you can see some logging, some from the fb call backs, which i implemented:

```
FB: taking saved token
FB: session already valid
FB: didLoadRawResponse
FB: didFailWithError
```

I HAD previously revoked the app's access through the apps dashboard, so i was expecting the 
 isSessionValid call to return false.  However it doesn't and still believes the session to be valid.  I must be misunderstanding the meaning of "session" here.

I have also tried calling **`extendAccessTokenIfNeeded`** to play nice with the new token system, however this achieved nothing.

So it strikes me this is a catch 22 situation, facebook tells me the token is good, but making a graph call fails.  Do i need to somehow handle the universe of token invalid error codes and **call `authorize` again**?

Trying to find out using the facebook "documentation" was driving me gently insane.

**How are others handling this issue?**

**EDIT 1:**

I now get the following error, and cannot get the previous one, this may have been due to switching on the 'remove offline_access' migration.
However, fundamentally the issue is the same.

```
FB: {"error":{"message":"Error validating access token: User xxxxx has not authorized application xxxxxx.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"error_subcode":458}}
```